# jimp.loadFont function renders non-English (Thai) font ugly with vowel character

Tags: node.js, fonts, libgdx, non-english, jimp

## Background

I've used Gatsby plugin to generate image using the font typing [source](https://github.com/plahteenlahti/gatsby-social-cards/blob/master/plugins/gatsby-plugin-social-sharing-cards/index.js), which is a simple node.js code.

```js
// ...
const titleFont = await jimp.loadFont(`${__dirname}/fonts/Title.fnt`)
// ...
```

This code use **montserrat** font from Google font, which is converted from `.ttf` to Bitmap (`.fnt`)

The tools is used to convert can be:

- https://ttf2fnt.com/
- [Hiero](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero)

So, the original code support image render properly, as you can see in my text `เราควรเพิ่มประสิทธิภาพของ Single Page Application โดยใช้ Server-side Rendering (SSR) หรือไม่`. This text is consist of Thai and English, and the rendered image show the expected result.

Thai font will be `?` symbol.
[image]

## Thai font problem

I'ved used **IBMPlexSansThai-Medium** font from Google font. and use [Hiero](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero) to convert the `.ttf` to `.fnt` file.

The result is ugly when display vowel.
[image]

Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thank you very much.